# Is there an algorithm for finding rows that have same sum of column values up to a threshold value?

Tags: algorithms, databases

I have a table like this (more specifically a nested dictionary)

| img | a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| img1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| img2 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| img3 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| img4 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| img5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| img6 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| img7 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| img8 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| img9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| img10 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ..... | … |  |  |  |  |

I need to add all the column names upto a threshold value, I need those rows which would give me the same sum for all columns.

for example, If I keep 5 as a threshold then it should give rows which sums upto 5 (5 *a*-> 5, *b*->5, *c*->5, *d*->5, *e*->5, *f*->5) and as it iterates through each rows, column should not exceed the threshold.

One way I thought of this was to add iteratively until one class fills up and then stop counting for that class. In my case

*a b c d e*

1img 0 0 1 0 1

2img 3 1 1 0 3

3img 7 0 0 0 1 (skips this as this exceeds the threshold)

4img 5 3 1 0 3 (*a* is full, ignores entire row for which has value for class *a*)

5img 0 3 1 0 5 (*e* is full, ignores entire row for which has value for class *a* and *e*)

6img 2 2 0 0 0 (since now *a* will become 7, it skips this step and jumps to next row)

and it should go on like that and finally returns those img which will satisfy the conditions. Sometimes the constraint cannot fill upto 5, so maybe at the end I try with 1 or 2 value more than threshold.

I made function manually which implements this exact same approach in python

```
def filter_by_threshold(threshold_value, data): 
....... for img, value
 in data.items(): skip_row = False
 for class, count in value.items():
     if class in max_counts:
         max_counts[class] = max(max_counts[class], count)
     else:
         max_counts[class] = count
     if count > threshold_value:
         skip_row = True
         break
 if skip_row:
     continue .......
```

Is there any algorithm which does this exact same thing in a more efficient way? I am doing this in Python defining as a function. Will it work if I consider the class name such a,b,c... as nodes and values as weight of nodes and consider any graphical approach? Also, I don't want to use pandas dataframe. I also thought of sorting the class in a way that the least number of classes gets filled up first but I think it will too difficult if I have a huge set of data. For the example case I considered only little rows but there are lot of rows and columns and I need to find a better way to select the images which can give me exact number sum for all the columns.

Also another thing that I need to consider is for this example
a b.....
img1 8
img2 10
img3 5
img4 6
img4 4

when I am adding each rows and if I keep threshold as 9, it should go through all possible rows and give me back img3 and img4, if I consider for large case sometimes it may not fulfil the criteria but atleast I can try one or two less more than the actual threshold. Also I need to consider not only for one class but for all the other classes/ columns.

Anyone have any idea, a better way of doing it?

I am new here so forgive me if I did any mistakes.
If you need more clarification please let me know :)

Comment: `e is full` how do I tell a *full* class /column from one *not full*, and what exactly/explicitly is the condition to ignore a row? FWIW, this looks a programming problem to me: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on/129632#129632)

Comment: As I iterate each step I check if one class gets filled, if it does, then I ignore that class for the rest of iterations meaning I take only those classes where the class value is 0. I ignore the row if it doesn't follow this condition. Thanks I thought since I don't have much coding in my problem I should ask here